# Contacts backup and restore program for dual SIM Android phone

Tags: android, backup, phone

I need program to backup and restore my contacts on Android phone.
It must:

1. backup and restore contacts
2. backup and restore as is:

   a. phone contacts to phone contacts

   b. first SIM contacts to first SIM contacts

   c. second SIM contacts to second SIM contacts

   d. Google contacts to Google contacts (this is good but not strongly required)
3. I need ability to view (and maybe to edit) backuped contacts on a desktop computer (maybe from simple text editor) with Ubuntu Linux.
4. I need ability to change type of contact (phone, SIM, Google, ...) one by one on my mobile phone and/or in backuped contacts on desktop computer.

P.S.: I have Android 4.4.

Comment: What about Android's own import and export feature for contacts? Can't you use that?

Comment: @einpoklum , How to backup all contacts with it to different files by contact type (Phone, Google, SIM1, SIM2, ...)? How to restore all contacts as it was type: Google as Google, Phone as Phone, SIM1 as SIM1, SIM2 as SIM2?

Answer (score 0):

There are apps available which let you backup your contacts and then restore them to your new phone. I have used few apps and I found them useful as they solved my problem and I am satisfied with their results. I am also posting them here for your convenience and I hope they solve your problem.

[Contacts Backup: Data Recovery, Transfer & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contacts.backup.transfer.restore.zp)

[SMS Backup & Restore Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestorePro)

[SMS Backup+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync)